# How to set the target path for bundle install?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

On my home box the `bundle install` command asks for my password and installs the gems in

```
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/...
```

But on my office computer they are installed in `~/.bundler/cache/git` (or at least cached there) and not installed in the main filesystem.

I can’t figure out how to set the path they are installed in. Please help!

Answer (score 10):

You can specify where the gems are installed by using

```
bundle install --path [directory]
```

This is not normally necessary; you can usually just do 'bundle install' and you're good to go.

When you want to include the gems for deployment, you will want to use

```
bundle package
```

which will, by default, put your gems in **./vendor/cache**. If you subsequently deploy the project and do

```
bundle install --deployment
```

Bundler will source the files from that directory and install them into **./vendor/bundle**. More information is available by doing

```
bundle help install
```

Hope this is useful.

Comment: I believe it should be `--path`, not `-path`.

Comment: `--path` flag is deprecated because it relies on being remembered across bundler invocations, which bundler will no longer do in future versions. 
Instead you can use:
`bundle config set --local path 'your_path'`

Answer (score 9):

As [Mohamed Hakki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5582257/mohamed-hakki) noted, the other answer is now **deprecated**.

---

You can now set the target path for Bundler using:

```
bundle config set --local path vendor/bundle
```

Here we specify the path `vendor/bundle` (which in my experience seems to be the most common and “standard” path), but you can specify any path you want (including `~/.bundler`).

This command actually creates a file within your working directory, `.bundle/config`, with the contents:

```
---
BUNDLE_PATH: "vendor/bundle"
```

Of course, we are using `vendor/bundle` as an example, but the `BUNDLE_PATH` will be whatever you specified as the path in the command invocation.

Once this file is in your working directory, all invocations of Bundler from the same working directory will use the path you specified.